# Get all the items NOT included in a giving order using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
orders:
- id
- date

item_order:
- order_id
- item_id

items:
- id
- desc
- price
```

Using Eloquent, how can I get all the items NOT included in a giving order (say, the order with `id` = 6)?

I'm trying to do relationships & subqueries, but without luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Did you try to get items from model Order->items() instead?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for checking for the existence or lack of existence of a relationship? `whereDoesntHave`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, `Using Eloquent, how can I get all the items NOT included in a giving order (say, the order with id = 6)?`, this sentence is unclear.

In other hand based on your explanation, below example gonna return list of orders with their items, except something you don't want:

```
$id = 6;

// Get list of orders with itemOrder.
Order::with('itemOrder' => function ($query) use $($id) {
    //make sure query don't return list of order items belong to order id = 6.
    $query->where('order_id', '!=,' $id)
})->get();
```

You will get list of `orders` with `item_order` but you will not get `item_order` for order with id of 6.

If this is not what you've asked please clarify and update your question for better explanation.

Based on your comment : `Your solution gives me the ORDERS, but I want all the ITEMS, except those of the order with id = 6.`, you can simply replace query with specified model and relations

```
$id = 6;
Item::with('itemOrder' => function ($query) use $($id) {
    $query->where('order_id', '!=,' $id)
})->get();

// Or,
// This one only return items with itemOrders and of course returned itemsOrder
// will be affected by query inside callback function
Item::whereHas('itemOrder' => function ($query) use $($id) {
    $query->where('order_id', '!=,' $id)
})->get();
```

Comment: thanks for you very interesting reply. Your solution gives me the ORDERS, but I want all the ITEMS, except those of the order with id = 6. Is this clearer?

Comment: @RicardoPérez Answer, updated.